# Jquery find li from text in session storage, then get the data-value

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I need to find text in a list based on the text in session storage, then get the data-value for that specific list item and set it to session storage.

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('thismodel')){
              var obj1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.thisyear);
              $("#vehic_sel_year-label-perf em").html(obj1);
              var obj2 = $('#vehic_sel_year-perf li').find(obj1).data('value');
              sessionStorage.setItem('model1', obj2);
        }
```

I feel like this shouldn't bee too difficult but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery is really easy.

```
var obj1 = 'Text 2';
var obj2 = $('li:contains("' + obj1 + '")', '#vehic_sel_year-perf').data('value');
$('#found').html(obj2);
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't get this to work either. Here's a sample of my html with data-values. The result is 'null'.

<ul id="vehic_sel_year">
<li value='1'>2016</li>
<li value='2'>2015</li>
<li value='3'>2014</li>
</ul>